# how can i insert into data when column has "(" character Postgresql DB?

Tags: sql, database

when i use python in vscode program, i use postgresql DB connection for parsing data and
insert to DB table.

but when i use character like "(" << occured some errors on code..

so i'd like to know how can i make it works?

below the code

```
            sql = "INSERT INTO elevator_2 (소재지1, 소재지2, 운행유효기간(시작일) , 운행유효기간(종료일) , 지역번호, 건물관리번호1, 건물관리번호2, 건물명, 건물용도명, 지상운행층수, 지하운행층수, 승강기번호, 승강기호기, 승강기구분명, 승강기형식명, 승강기종류명, 승강기관리번호1, 승강기관리번호2, 모델명, 승강기재개일, 승강기상태, 최초설치일자, 최종검시기관, 설치일자, 설치장소, 최종검사일, 최종검사종류, 최종검사결과, 적재하중, 제조업체명, 제조업체전화번호, 제조업체코드, 보수업체코드, 보수업체명, 보수업체연락처, 기계실여부, 관리주체명, 관리주체연락처, 휴폐지일자, 휴폐지사유, 최대정원, 정격속도, 승강기운행층수, 선임여부/운행관리자명 , 운행관리자연락처, 승강기운행구간, 시/군/구코드 , 표준키번호, 하도급/공동수급 , 우편번호1, 우편번호2, 페이지번호) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
            cur.execute(sql, (item['address1'], item['address2'], item['applcBeDt'], item['applcEnDt'], item['areaNo'], item['buldMgtNo1'], item['buldMgtNo2'], item['buldNm'], item['buldPrpos'], item['divGroundFloorCnt'], item['divUndgrndFloorCnt'], item['elevatorNo'], item['elvtrAsignNo'], item['elvtrDivNm'], item['elvtrFormNm'], item['elvtrKindNm'], item['elvtrMgtNo1'], item['elvtrMgtNo2'], item['elvtrModel'], item['elvtrResmptDe'], item['elvtrStts'], item['frstInstallationDe'], item['inspctInstt'], item['installationDe'], item['installationPlace'], item['lastInspctDe'], item['lastInspctKind'], item['lastResultNm'], item['liveLoad'], item['manufacturerName'], item['manufacturerTelno'], item['mnfcturCpnyCd'], item['mntCpnyCd'], item['mntCpnyNm'], item['mntCpnyTelno'], item['mrYn'], item['partcpntNm'], item['partcpntTelno'], item['pauseAblDe'], item['pauseAbleResn'], item['ratedCap'], item['ratedSpeed'], item['shuttleFloorCnt'], item['shuttleMngrNm'], item['shuttleMngrTelno'], item['shuttleSection'], item['sigunguCd'], item['standardKey'], item['subcntrCpny'], item['zipCd1'], item['zipCd2'], jsonDict['response']['body']['pageNo'] ))
            conn.commit()
```

when i want to use "(" character for column name.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Column names containing special characters (expect _ [underscore] ) need to be enclosed in double quotation marks.
As I find the first bracket in your third column:

운행유효기간(시작일) needs to be changed to "운행유효기간(시작일)"

The quotation marks need to be escaped, as you prepare your SQL-Statement as a string.

A shortended version would look like this:

```py
sql = "INSERT INTO elevator_2 (소재지1, 소재지2, \"운행유효기간(시작일)\")"
cur.execute(sql, (item['address1'], item['address2'], item['applcBeDt'])
```

But I would strongly recommend to use column names that don't require quotation marks as these have to be used for every reference to the column.
Maybe you should check if your database is normalized enough, as I can't imagine a field that would require additional information in form of a bracket.

[Postgres Documentation mentioning the double qoutes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS)
[DB-Fiddle with Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/LbmpJLUb)
[W3Schools about Normalization](https://www.w3schools.in/dbms/database-normalization)
[W3Schools about python Escape Characters](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp)

Comment: HI. 
I tried to add " character already, but it doens't works :(
cause i guess there is already " character in the 'sql' variable.
how can i fix this code working..? :(

Comment: [W3Schools about String Escape in python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp) That is what you are looking for.

Comment: wow.. so sorry i missed link you posted in the comments :) 
thank you so much!